# "sudo apt-get install traceroute" showing error

Tags: lubuntu, dpkg, traceroute

Im using Ubuntu 20.04 in the VM and trying to install traceroute. However, I tried the following ways:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install traceroute

which shows the

"E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."

How can I resolve and then install traceroute?

Comment: Have you run the `dpkg --configure -a` suggested to fix your packages issues created but not fixed in prior commands you've executed on your box?

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I did but all in vain. However, I solved it, just ran that in the root, by using sudo -s

Comment: @jarvvis Please post "I solved it. I just ran that as root, by using `sudo -s`" as an answer to your own question instead of as a comment.